# Hide Listbox ScrollBar created from code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have this code to create a listbox on my Menu.xaml code behind (Menu.xaml.vb):

```
            Dim mm As New ListBox()
            AddHandler mm.SelectionChanged, AddressOf Me.ListBox_SelectionChanged

            mm.FontSize = 20
            Dim nn As New ListBoxItem
            nn.Content = "NOTIFICATIONS:"
            nn.Foreground = Brushes.White
            nn.Background = Brushes.DarkSlateBlue
            nn.FontSize = 44
            nn.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold

            mm.Items.Add(nn)
```

Now I wanted to disable the scrolling, or in other case hide the scrollbar but if I check on mm properties there is no reference to the Scroll

any help or clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(mm, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(mm, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
```